# May not be able to finish minor that I noted on my PhD applications

Tags: graduate-admissions, minor

I applied to graduate schools and have a couple of interviews lined up in February. I listed my statistics minor on my application (which is declared on my transcript and everything) but I may not be able to finish it because I am on the waitlist for the final two classes I need. I am doing everything in my control to try to get into them (emailing/petitioning professors, talking with an academic advisor), but there is no guarantee that I will be able to enroll if I don't get off of the waitlist.

This will not affect my ability to graduate with my neuroscience major. Additionally, the classes that I need to take are not very relevant. In the event that I am unable to finish the minor, how do I inform the admissions committees where I have interviews, and will it substantially affect my application?

Comment: No need to bring it up unasked. No one will look at your transcript when you enrolled to double-check your major and then boot you if you didn't finish. If someone asks ... don't lie

Comment: My department has an unofficial policy of helping students in your situation. I highly recommend talking to the instructors of the classes you need and also to the director of undergrad studies of the department that offers the classes you want to take.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you, as a longtime member of an admissions committee for a prestigious PhD program, the committee is looking at the depth and breadth of your preparation. Your major and minor are less important. What courses and experiences have you had, and how did you do?

Another commenter said that disruptions at the end of one’s studies are not uncommon. I agree with this.

Lesser programs might be overly rigid about majors and prerequisites. The better programs engage in holistic review to see the full spectrum of an applicant’s preparation, experience, and non cognitive attributes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Each situation is unique. But if I was recruiting a PhD students in Neuroscience, I would be more interested in seeing how much knowledge students has in my fiend of research rather than a statistic minor. PhD is itself a long journey and you will have plenty of chances to take courses if you like. So as long as you have fulfilled other requirements and have good research interest match with your advisor it should be okay. If you can take stat minor that would be great if not it should be okay.

On a side note, you may get chance to do stat minor as a PhD student. You could transfer courses to fulfill requirements for stat minor from your current (assuming you are completing masters degree with several stat courses) school towards your PhD. So, if you could do it, else don’t worry too much.

Comment: Where are you that minors in doctoral programs are even a thing? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Buffy I hadn't either, but at least the [Indiana University School of Medicine **requires** a minor.](https://medicine.iu.edu/graduate-degrees/phd/indianapolis/minors)

Comment: In my materials science PhD we were required to do a concentration outside of the department. For me that was 3 courses in quantum optics (useful in various laser experiments).

Comment: @buffy There are plenty of minors at PHD levels. Stat minor is one of the very common field. Some university requires someone from the department to be in the dissertation committee and some just require to fulfill course hours.

Comment: @Dr.Baje Mine requires both

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it would be an issue unless it is specifically required for entry into your desired program, but to be completely honest, make sure that at some point you inform people of the situation. This might come in an interview: "Oh, by the way, I might not... due to waiting lists".

As long as completion is still a possibility and you haven't been closed out, I don't think you need to update applications, but you don't want to leave the impression that you have padded your CV.

I'll note that final year disruptions, during the doctoral application process aren't especially rare. And I doubt that extensive statistics is required for application to a neuroscience degree, though some specifics might be needed for certain sorts of research. But that is also true of many fields that depend on statistical methods.

---

Depending on your university, it might be worth a visit with the department head in statistics, especially if one or more of those courses is actually required. There might be a way to expedite your attendance. I don't guess this is especially likely, but it might be worth the trip.

Comment: The classes aren't required for the programs and they honestly aren't very relevant. As you mentioned, I just don't want to be perceived as padding my CV. Thanks for the advice!